# Can we having optional arguments in tcsh alias?

Tags: arguments, alias, tcsh, option-type

I have the following alias

`alias ackalias "acknoredirect !:2-$ '^[\sun]alias.?(!:1)' ~/.alias"`

The problem is that it doesn't work if I do `ackalias tmux`; it always needs 2 or more arguments. For example, the following works great: `ackalias tmux -A 2 -B 2`

Is it possible to replace !:2-$ in the alias definition with something that says that 2nd and more arguments are optional?

**Update**
@Mark As you suggested, I tried out the below simple example and found issues when I have 2 or more optional arguments. Check the below example:

`alias test2 'echo \!:1* \!:2* \!:3* \!:4*'
test2 a
test2 a b
test2 a b c
test2 a b c d
test2 a b c d e`

The output was:

`a
a b b
a b c b c c
a b c d b c d c d d
a b c d e b c d e c d e d e`

I might need to add if conditions but it should eventually work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked!

`` alias test4 'set arg1 = `echo \!:1* | awk '"'"'{ print $1 }'"'"'`; \\
                 echo -n "Arg num 1 = $arg1 "; \\
                 set arg2 = `echo \!:2* | awk '"'"'{ print $1 }'"'"'`; \\
                 echo -n "Arg num 2 = $arg2 "; \\
                 set arg3 = `echo \!:3* | awk '"'"'{ print $1 }'"'"'`; \\
                 echo -n "Arg num 3 = $arg3 "; \\
                 set arg4 = `echo \!:4* | awk '"'"'{ print $1 }'"'"'`; \\
                 echo -n "Arg num 4 = $arg4 "; \\
                 set arg5 = `echo \!:5* | awk '"'"'{ print $1 }'"'"'`; \\
                 echo -n "Arg num 5 = $arg5 "; \\
                 echo ""; \\
                '
    test4 abc
    test4 abc def ghi
    test4 abc def ghi jkl
    test4 abc def ghi jkl mno
    test4 abc def ghi jkl mno pqr ``

*I soon need to start converting to zsh..*

Comment: I wrote a little blog post explaining this: http://kaushalmodi.github.io/2014/03/12/writing-aliases-with-optional-arguments-in-tcsh/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
alias ackalias "acknoredirect \!:2* '^[\sun]alias.?(\!:1)' ~/.alias"
```

(note I also added escapes before the !'s)

Comment: Thanks, that was a pretty close answer. I was testing it out and found issues. I have updated my original question with explanation.